# Installing Windows 7 After Replacing HDD in a laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, installation, windows-installation

I have a Toshiba laptop which has a dead hard drive. The user has also lost their recovery CDs. I was wondering then if it is possible to download the official Win7 ISO's from here (http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/) and install it on a brand new HDD in the same laptop using the existing Product Key.

On the Certificate Of Authenticity it has "Windows 7 Home Prem OA" and also has the product key.

I hope that made sense.

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

Just make sure you download the correct version based upon the license but what you are asking is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 0):

If the ISO contains an OEM version then it will likley work with the COA/Key you have, and as noted by @Dave Rook, be legal.  However, it is unusual to get an OEM ISO.  The COA may not work with the downloaded ISO as it is not OEM.  Also, if the original install was not SP1, it may have an issue with that so you may have to try and see what happens.

It may be necessary to contact the vendor for recovery media.